# Legal prose in Corda

Tags: corda

Can someone explain what is it legal prose in Corda? I understood that it is a document, which is used to solve conflicts, but i didnt find any information how it looks like. And how is it linked with smart contract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Contract` class can be annotated with the `@LegalProseReference` annotation. This annotation associates the contract with a document that restates the constraints imposed by verify in legal prose terms. This is not required, but can be useful in contexts where it is expected that legal contracts will take precedence over the software implementations in case of disagreement.

`@LegalProseReference` takes a single parameter, `uri`, which identifies the legal prose document the contract is associated with:

```
@LegalProseReference(uri = "foo.bar.com/my-legal-doc.html")
public class MyContract implements Contract {
    @Override
    public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) {
        // Contract logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: one question joel. so I got this legal  doc my-legal-doc.html. so what happens in case the verify method doesn't throw an exception? and what happens in case verify does throw an exception do I show this legal doc to the user that read this legal doc. That this is why the contract failed? you mention legal contract takes precedence-> so if verify method throws exception then how does legal doc takes precedence? I go through this doc find what's wrong and manually verify the tx? also how manually?

Comment: Interesting points. Can you raise this as a separate question?

Comment: raised it as a separate question only to be downvoted
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313807/legal-prose-usage-corda