# How to access legal prose document mentioned in Contract Corda

Tags: java, corda

This is in continuation of [Legal Prose Usage Corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313807/legal-prose-usage-corda). I want to understand how we can use document mentioned in `@LegalProseReference`.

1. Once the transaction is submitted - where is this document (mentioned in URI) is stored.
2. How different nodes can see and check/download this associated Legal Prose document.

Answer (score 1):

`@LegalProseReference` is simply a URI for some legal representation of the contract. Note that:

- Corda does not prescribe the format of this URI. It could be anything that uniquely identifies the contract
- The document the URI points to is not stored on the node, and has to be located and checked outside of Corda

Comment: Taking the example that mentioned in the post that refer in my question  - if @LegalProseReference(uri = "foo.bar.com/my-legal-doc.html"). Now, if this my-legal-doc.html is not saved in node database and then what will happen if this my-legal-doc.html changed tomorrow. If there is no Audit of than what's the point of having it. Ideally it Corda should kept a copy when this was submitted. And then if document is not stored by Corda then how Corda can say that it could be used as Legal Tool.

Comment: One option would be to pass a hash of the contract as the string. This will prevent the contents from changing.

Comment: yes but then is not not worth to just use attachment? I was more thinking the usage of Legal prose but with the way it's been implemented can find how it could be use as Legal tool in court.

Comment: Any more suggestion?

Comment: You could use an attachment for this purpose, yes. The `LegalProseReference` is only useful if you can point to the legal contract using some external URI.