# Implementing Legal Prose Templates

Tags: corda

I’ve seen the video on legal prose [1] but can't find any actual API within Corda with support for legal prose documents per se, i.e. components relevant to legal prose templates and parameters.

Besides support for attachments, is there anything out there to help with legal prose templates or is this something I need to implement from scratch?

To be clear, @LegalProseReference seems irrelevant to "nodes trying to reach agreement on parameterised legal documents". What I need to do is:

1. Define a prose template
2. Have the template variable fields filled during a flow using values from the input state
3. Attach the resulting document

[1] https://vimeo.com/album/4555732

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Legal prose in Corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223980/legal-prose-in-corda)

Comment: Clarified use case

Comment: Thanks. What's the use-case? Is it nodes trying to reach agreement on parameterised legal documents?

Comment: Yes, that is the case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a state representing a parameterised legal document:

```
public class LegalProseState implements ContractState {
    private Party partyA;
    private Party partyB;
    private int amount;

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "%s owes %s the sum of %d US dollars.",
                partyA.getName(),
                partyB.getName(),
                amount);
    }

    public LegalProseState(Party partyA, Party partyB, int amount) {
        this.partyA = partyA;
        this.partyB = partyB;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return ImmutableList.of(partyA, partyB);
    }

    public Party getPartyA() {
        return partyA;
    }

    public Party getPartyB() {
        return partyB;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

You can then define a flow to issue these `LegalProseState`s onto the ledger. The flow will:

- Instantiate a new `LegalProseState`, parameterised using the parameters you pass into the state's constructor
- Add the new state as an output to a new transaction
- Have the transaction signed by both parties
- Have the transaction stored by both parties

The nodes will then both have a signed copy of a parameterised legal prose document.